# glob function won't find file with wildcard

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that displays files in my directory like this:

```
lstFiles = os.listdir(dir)   
nPathLen = len(dir)

for filename in lstFiles:
     print(filename)
```

This results in:

```
graph.png
test.jdx
```

Then i am trying to use a wildcard to limit the results like so:

```
import glob  

dirlist = glob.glob(dir + "*.jdx")
print(dirlist)
for pathname in dirlist:
    filename = pathname[nPathLen:]
    print(filename)
```

All i get for output is:

```
[]
```

Am i missing something here? Is there some situations where glob won't work ?

Comment: Does `dir` have a trailing slash? Try `glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, "*.jdx"))`

Comment: Oh, no it doesn't but it does have " \ " between each folder for its directory could that be causing problems ?

Comment: yes, you need a path separator between dir and the file part. You could print `dir + ".jdx"` to be sure. You haven't given an example path, but suppose its `C:\Users\Bob\Downloads` and now you glob `C:\Users\Bob\Downloads*.jdx`. `os.path.join` fixes that.

Comment: Ah thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although a directory doesn't need a trailing path separator just to find it on the drive (`os.listdir()` for instance), if you want to address the contents of that directory, the separator is needed. Python supplies `os.path.join` to join paths in a platform independent manner. Its a bit better than putting the slash in yourself because it doesn't double-add it if one is already there. Some operating systems care about that sort of thing.

```
dirlist = glob.glob(os.path.join(dir, "*.jdx"))
```